# Is there any Javascript feature that lets you check if an element was closed?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any parameter/function in JS that tells you if an element was closed with an ending tag? ... for [this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932075/detect-if-iframes-document-is-malformed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JS is simply the scripting language that provides access to the DOM of the page. The DOM is preparsed from the page source before you ever get access to it. Any attempt to access the page source will return the pre-corrected source as determined by the browser during the initial parsing phase.

So in a word, no.

Comment: Pity that browsers don't give you access to such basic validation features.

Comment: @Jeremy: IMO, the reason is that a browser is not primarily a developer tool.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSource() {
    var xhr = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', window.location.href, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}
```

Taking this approach you'd have to parse the HTML yourself - a momentous task.